# Web Scraping: how to extract this kind of div tag?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I am looking at a tag :

[image].

When I write a code,

```py
message = soup.find("div", {"class": "text-msg-container"})
```

it gave me none. What are `_ngcontent-vex-c62` and `data-e2e-text-message-content` tags? Do I need to include them too? How should I write them to get the div tag?

Answer (score 2):

**You can't** because the div isn't there when you send a `GET` request to get the page code.

That page is built using Angular framework which produce SPA(Single Page Application) which means you can't **scrape** data from it when you send a `GET` request because the data isn't there.
The data is being generated by Javascript code which needs to run first to add the required data to the webpage.

You need to use another way that allows Javascript code to run first then you try to get the data you want.

Comment: It does seem likely that this div is dynamically created, but how can you know it is Angular? There doesn't seem to be sufficient info in the question.

Comment: I knew it's using Angular from `_ngcontent`. Usually Angular uses `ng` as a prefix for its components. I recommend you using an extension to show you what technologies the website built with like Wappalyzer extension.

Comment: Thank you for the information! I quite understand why it gives me None!

Answer (score 1):

try this please

```
message = soup.find("div", _class="text-msg-container")
```

Comment: Still gives me, 'none'!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find class `text-msg-container`, try Selenium. It will find any locator easily.

```
import unittest    
from selenium import webdriver
    
    class PythonSearch(unittest.TestCase):
    
        def setUp(self):
            self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    
        def test_search(self):
            driver = self.driver
            driver.get("http://www.yoursite.com")
            elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".text-msg-container")
    
        def tearDown(self):
            self.driver.close()
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        unittest.main()
```

Use `driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')` if you are testing Chrome. Look here for more info https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started .
Getting started for Selenium https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#simple-usage

Comment: Okay, I will try selenium! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

i hope that works

```
from selenium import webdriver

path = "C:/chromedriver.exe"    ### path to downloaded chromedriver on your 
                                #pc change this directory or put the same location C:

driver = webdriver.Chrome(path) ## your browser change it if you are not using chrome 
driver.get("website link")

out = driver.find_element_by_class_name("text-msg-container")
print(out.text)
```

Comment: Okay, I will try it! Thank you!